# How can I read the count step from healthkit plugin ngcordova for ios?

Tags: iphone, ionic-framework, ngcordova, healthkit

I'm using ionic app that read the number of step in health application that provided by iphone , so I need to read the number of step
I am using health kit plugin from ng-Cordova : 
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/healthkit/

```
module.controller('ThisCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaHealthKit) {
$cordovaHealthKit.isAvailable().then(function(yes) {
// Is available
}, function(no) {
// Is not available
});
})
```

and I want to use or read the number of step ...
I just saw a birthday date , gender, weight and height .
so if it exists a number of step ?